# React-native app doesn't display the right screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When clicked on 'Questionnaire' button, I want BodyScreen to be displayed (seen in Routes.js), but only LoadingView is being displayed -please refer to the emulator screenshot below.

Here is the code for LoadingView, BodyScreen(which uses LoadingView) and Routes(which specifies the navigations on the main page):

**LoadingView/component.js:**

```
...
import LoadingScreen from "../../screens/LoadingScreen";

const LoadingView = ({ predicate, style, text, children }) => {
  return predicate() ? (
    <View style={style}>{children}</View>
  ) : (
    <LoadingScreen style={styles.loading} text={text} />
  );
};

LoadingView.propTypes = {
  predicate: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default LoadingView;
```

**BodyScreen/component.js**

```
...
import LoadingView from "../../views/LoadingView";
import { FRONT } from "../../../store/OrganStore/constants";

const getTitle = side => {
  if (side == FRONT) {
    return translations.t("BodyScreen.front");
  } else {
    return translations.t("BodyScreen.back");
  }
};

const BodyScreen = ({ navigation, organStore, questionStore }) => (
  <LoadingView predicate={() => organStore.loaded} style={styles.view}>

    {/*debug July*/}
    <Text style={styles.title}>{getTitle(FRONT)}</Text>
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <SvgContainer navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        style={styles.button}
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={() => navigation.pop()}
      >
        {translations.t("BodyScreen.exit")}
      </Button>
      <LoadingView
        predicate={() =>
          questionStore.loaded.slider &&
          questionStore.loaded.radio &&
          questionStore.loaded.text
        }
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <EitherButton
          predicate={() => questionStore.available}
          style={styles.button}
          textA={translations.t("BodyScreen.next")}
          onPressA={() => navigation.navigate("Question")}
          textB={translations.t("BodyScreen.submit")}
          onPressB={() => {
            submitOrgans(organStore.organs);
            navigation.pop();
          }}
        />
      </LoadingView>
    </View>
  </LoadingView>
);

export default BodyScreen;
```

**Routes.js** where the BodyScreen is used

```
import BodyScreen from '../components/screens/BodyScreen';
...
{/* Questionnaire part for athlete */}
<Scene key="Questionnaire"  >
    {/* check assigned Questionnairee */}
    <Scene key="userQues" component={BodyScreen} title="Question List"/>
    {/* check text Questionnare */}
    <Scene key="questionText" component={Questions_Text} title="Text" />
    {/* check RadioButton Questionnare */}
    <Scene key="questionRB" component={Questions_RB} title="Radio Button"/>
    {/* check CheckBox Questionnare */}
    <Scene key="questionCB" component={Questions_CB} title="Check Box"/>
</Scene>
```

The above code works on a separate app. I am trying to integrate this page to another application and I am facing this issue where only the LoadingView gets displayed when clicked on 'Questionnaire' scene instead of the BodyScreen.

[image]

Comment: put your code on github and leave a link here

Comment: that is because predicate() is returning false?